# Can dml commands be used on one database twice during runtime?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Beginner here
So here is an example I was working on
A Emp database with id name and position etc
and in windows form, I had this code

```
    private void test()
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = createConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand sqlcomm = conn.CreateCommand();
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO emp VALUES('15','xxx','writer')";
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.close();
    }
```

the above function worked fine.
Then I had another function afterward:

```
private void update()
 {
        SQLiteConnection conn = createConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand sqlcomm = conn.CreateCommand();
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "update emp set name='ahah' where id= 15";
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
 }
```

Theoretically it should update the value, but the entire form freezes during runtime when executing the sqlcomm of update. What did i do wrong? Why can't i do this? How should i fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume that you are calling `test` and `update` method one after another in the same code block. and `test` method runs fine but `update` method freezes the UI. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, test is called before update, and they are called in the same form.

Comment: Can you share the code which calls these method? Are you call these methods in some button click event?